# How to customise Einstein Opportunity Score Top Positive and Negative

Tags: lightning, process-builder, opportunity, einstein, opportunity-lineitem

I'm new here and I'm Salesforce business developer with less salesforce technical background.

Recently, we have turn on Einstein Opportunity Score as per the image attached, i m finding the way to customize Einstein Opportunity Score Top Positive and Negative which are not align with our SF compliance.

The answer from IT developer is impossible to customise therefore need many helps from you guys to guide me where i can customise or last is turn off this feature if really cant do.

[image]